# Hausdorff condition for covering map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here's is the definition of covering map given by Glen E. Bredon:

A map $p:X\rightarrow Y$ os called a covering map if $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, arciwse connected, locally arcwwise connected, and if each point $y\in Y$ has an arcwise connected neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a nonempty disjoint union of sets $U_{\alpha}$ on which $p|_{U_{\alpha}}$ is a homeomorphism $U_{\alpha}\rightarrow U$.

I can't see the condition of being Hausdorff is needed in the proof of all the subsequent theorems (The Path Lifting Property, The Covering Homotopy Theorem), so can anyone find any counterexample for the following proposition?

If an arcwise connected and locally arcwise connected space $Y$ has a nontrivial covering map (without Hausdorff condition) then $\pi_{1}(Y,y_{0})\ne 1$.

Comment: The Hausdorff assumption is unnecessary. I made the same mistake in my book now "Topology and Groupoids".(amazon). But that is still the only book to use fibrations and coveringmorphisms of groupoids,.